# Change eval 2k3 licence to a tech net licence

Tags: windows-server-2003, license-key

Am currently using the free 120 eval version of Server 2003 that come with the MCSA MS Press books.  Awkwarly my studies have progressed less quickly than I hoped (I blame the Bad Idea Bears) and the end of the 120 period is approaching.  I have access to technet now and can get hold of two keys from there.  Does anyone know of a way to upgrade an eval license to a full license without a full reinstall (which although good practice is time consuming and utterly soul destroying)?  Some kind of clever SID change or registry hack perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a recommended practice, but it looks like some people have had success by doing a repair installation.

[Details are in this thread.](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/932666.htm)

Comment: I had seen that but it does look like the only viable option.  Not being a production environment I suppose it is no big deal if it is a little bit cack handed lol.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, sorry there isn't a more elegant fix.  When you are dealing with enterprise OS's, though, you are often limited in what you can do without breaking things :)

Comment: unfortunately it did not quite go very smoothly.  still, was good practice lol

Comment: Yeah, thats probably why it's not recommended!  At least you learned something :)